# Please add a "flushmate" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't have enough points in this group to add tags. Please add a "flushmate" tag so I can affix to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That would be a vendor specific tag. I don't believe those are encouraged here, and I'm not a fan of adding them myself. In fact we've been cleaning up some questions that used trademarked names to refer to the more generic term for the product.

Also, if the tag was created, the system should delete it automatically after a timeout if it is only used on a single question.